# Cloud Datastore php API - setTransaction()

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running a php application on google app engine and somewhere in the code I need to save some data in the Cloud Datastore (line 5 here):

```
<?php
$DB = new Database($google_api_config);

foreach ($items as $item) {
  $DB->save_entity("kind", item['id'], $data_to_store);
}
?>
```

And the class:

```
<?php
class Database {
  //other codes...

  public function save_entity($kind, $identifier, $values){
    $key = $this->create_key($kind, $identifier);

    $property_map = [];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $property_value = $this->create_roperty($value[0],$value[2]);
        $property_map[$value[1]] = $property_value;
    }

    $entity = new Google_Service_Datastore_Entity();
    $entity->setKey($key);
    $entity->setProperties($property_map);

    $mutation = new Google_Service_Datastore_Mutation();
    $mutation->setUpsert([$entity]);

    $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_CommitRequest();
    $req->setMode('NON_TRANSACTIONAL');
    $req->setMutation($mutation);

    $this->dataset->commit($this->dataset_id, $req, []);
  }
}
?>
```

As you can see, saving process is in a loop and needs to run several Commit requests very quickly. It works fine, but once in a while it doesn't and I can see the operation was partially done. Some items were saved but the rest not.

**The Question is:**
Can I run the whole foreach loop in a transaction and make sure that all items were saved? I also don't know how to implement it in php using the Datastore PHP Client Library API.

I'm not exactly sure, but something like this:

```
//start a transaction
//run the loop
//terminate the transaction
```

Comment: Are all the saved entities in the same entity group?  If not, you will most likely run into the limit (5) for XG [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions).

Comment: What is the same entity group? Do you mean the same "kind"? (Yes, they are the same kind)

Comment: No. Entity groups are an important Datastore concept that you ought to [familiarise yourself](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Ancestor_paths) with before embarking on any development. Entity Groups have an impact on write performance, transactions and read consistency.

Comment: @BehnamRasooli Were they in the same entity group or not? this can change the way to answer this question ^^

Comment: Yeah, the same group. In fact there is no hierarchically structured in my database. Everything is a root entity and no children.

Comment: hmmm, if there is no children, then it's not the same group. but okay. YOu need to read on this here https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Transactions_and_entity_groups. You can't have a transaction on more than 24 groups. If everything is root, means you can't have it on more than 24 entities.

Comment: So long as it's within the entity group limit, you can easily commit a series of entities in one single transaction. I have some samples in my PHP library for Datastore here (which wraps the Google SDK)  https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: @Tom So, how does it apply to my situation?  

`$obj_store->beginTransaction();`

`// Data changed within a transaction`
`$obj_store->upsert($obj_entity);`

`// Not transactional`
`$obj_store->delete($obj_entity);`

Does it mean I can do this?

`$obj_store->beginTransaction();`

`foreach ($items as $item) {`
`//some code here to make each $obj_entity ready for storing`

`$obj_store->upsert($obj_entity);`
`}`

Comment: @Patrice I only need max 10 entities to update. So it doesn't exceed the limit.

Comment: You can pass in an array of entities to the php-gds library. And they are upserted in a single call together (and optionally a single transaction). I'll try and put a gist together...

Comment: OK, so XG transactions don't appear to be supported in the JSON API for Datastore... I'm awaiting a response from Google.

Comment: @BehnamRasooli yeah, 10 shouldn't be a problem. So your basic answer would be "yes you can do it with a transaction".

Comment: @Patrice thanks, but how can I do it without using any library?

Comment: @BehnamRasooli There is the cloud datastore API you could explore. I haven't played with it (I usually use ndb or Objectify), https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/beginTransaction